# Best practice for clearing an array

Tags: php

I have an array that I would like to clear the values out of and I'm wondering what the best way to accomplish this is.

I tried setting it to nothing:

```
$array = array();

... later on
$array = "";
```

Afterwards I'll add new values to it later:

```
foreach($something as $thing):
    $array[] = $thing['item'];
endforeach;
```

And it seems to have done what I needed it too. But after a quick search online I'm seeing a lot of recommendations to do the following instead:

```
unset($array);
$array = array();
```

Is there any difference between this action and the one I performed up top?

Comment: Option 3) Just don't reuse your variables and stay sane :-)

Comment: `$array = array();` to make it empty. `$array = null` to make it null.... `unset($array['something]) ` to unset 'something'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $array to "" sets your variable to a string value, and unset removes the variable.  Since you are just trying to clear the array, then $array = array() should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `array()` explicitly defines it as an array. Your first statement `$array = ""` sets it to an empty string. Using unset will "reset" the variable, so it's neither a string or array until you assign a value to it, and `$array = array()` simply defines it as a new blank array.